# Using Automated Build in Docker Can't Style with Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, angular, docker

I'm learning to use Docker to develop complex apps locally and have decided to use angular2 as a starting point.

I have used angular-cli and pulled the image from: https://hub.docker.com/r/trion/ng-cli/

which has worked really well and I'm making progress. However, having updated my code base to test if Bootstrap is importing, I am seeing no styling. If anyone could suggest how we could overcome this, I'd be eternally grateful:

code:

(Module)

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AlertModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AlertModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

styles array from angular-cli.json

```
"styles": [
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "styles.css"
],
```

code from the template:

```
<h1>
    {{title}}
</h1>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Film Title</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let film of films">
        <td>{{ film.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ film.name }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<alert type="success">hello</alert>
```

Tried a couple of hacky methods, but nothing is working. Is this anything to do with there being no Dockerfile? Just learning Docker now, so any help appreciated.

Comment: got it running, by using the CDNs from bootstrap and jquery, but this doesnt seem like good practice. Surely, we can import this all from npm?

Comment: This is not related to a missing Dockerfile. The docker image you are using is already built using a Dockerfile, but you don't need one when just using docker for an Angular CLI build container. Do you get any errors from your angular cli?

Answer (score 1):

This might not be Angular nor Docker related, but more an issue with the project configuration.

In order for styles to get imported, you have two options:

Either you can add then to the project via the "styles" property in the .angular-cli.json. For this you need to know that all the file-definitions are relative to the `src` folder, so your definition won't work, you'd have to use something like this:

```
   "styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
        "styles.css"
      ],
```

Or you can import them via a css import from within the styles.css file like this:

```
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
```